# Swift - access to Dictionary of a singleton causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, dictionary, ios8

I have an app managing a simple stocks portfolio. Amongst other things, it keeps a record of the required exchange rates in a dictionary, like so:
[ EURUSD=X : 1.267548 ]
This disctionary is a Dictionary property of a singleton called CurrencyRateStore.

When updating the stocks quotations, it checks for an updated exchange rate and updates the dictionary with the following code:

```
CurrencyRateStore.sharedStore()[symbol] = fetchedRate.doubleValue
```

That calls:

```
subscript(index: String) -> Double? {
    get {
        return dictionary[index]
    }
    set {
        // FIXME: crashes when getting out of the app (Home button) and then relaunching it
            dictionary[index] = newValue!
            println("CurrencyRateStore - updated rate for \(index) : \(newValue!)")
    }
}
```

The first time the app is started, it works fine.
But if I quit the app (with the Home button) and then relaunch it, the currency rates are updated again, but this time, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the line

```
dictionary[index] = newValue!
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

[EDIT] Here is the thread in the debug navigator:
[image]

I tried to update the dictionary without a subscript, like so:

```
CurrencyRateStore.sharedStore().dictionary[symbol] = fetchedRate.doubleValue
```

but without more success. Same if I use the function updateValue:forKey:
I didn't have the issue in Objective-C.

Thanks for your help !

[EDIT] Here is the whole class **CurrencyRateStore**:

```
class CurrencyRateStore {

// MARK: Singleton
class func sharedStore() -> CurrencyRateStore! {
    struct Static {
        static var instance: CurrencyRateStore?
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        Static.instance = CurrencyRateStore()
    }

    return Static.instance!
}

// MARK: Properties

/** Dictionary of currency rates used by the portfolio, presented like  [ EURUSD=X : 1.3624 ] */
var dictionary = [String : Double]()

/** Returns a sorted array of all the keys on the currency rates dictionary */
var allKeys: [String] {
var keysArray = Array(dictionary.keys)
    keysArray.sort {$0 < $1}
    return keysArray
}

init() {
    if let currencyRateDictionary: AnyObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(currencyRateArchivePath) {
        dictionary = currencyRateDictionary as [String : Double]
    }
}

subscript(index: String) -> Double? {
    get {
        return dictionary[index]
    }
    set {
        // FIXME: crashes when getting out of the app (Home button) and then relaunching it
        // (ApplicationWillEnterForeground triggers updateStocks)
            dictionary[index] = newValue!
            println("CurrencyRateStore - updated rate for \(index) : \(newValue!)")
    }
}


func deleteRateForKey(key: String) {
    dictionary.removeValueForKey(key)
}


/** Removes all currency rates from the Currency rate store */
func deleteAllRates()
{
    dictionary.removeAll()
}


// MARK: Archive items in CurrencyRateStore
var currencyRateArchivePath: String { // Archive path
var documentDirectories: Array = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

    // Get the only document directory from that list
    let documentDirectory: AnyObject = documentDirectories.first!

    return documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("currencyRates.archive")
}

func saveChanges()-> Bool
{
    // return success or failure
    return NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(dictionary, toFile: currencyRateArchivePath)
}

}
```

Comment: Could you post the entire error log? Maybe that can help

Comment: Could you also share some relevant parts of `CurrencyRateStore`? At least the singleton implementation, the declaration of the dictionary property

Comment: But there is no log on a EXC_BAD_ACCESS ... You mean, the thread in the debug navigator ?

Comment: If you are running in simulator, check the `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/` folder

Comment: In the simulator, it works ... it crashes only when running on a real iPhone 6 ... wait, I'll try and delete the app from the device, and then install it again.

Comment: Nope, still the same. Aha, but here is an error log on my device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63519/discussion-between-fred-a-and-antonio).

Comment: At the point where you crash, or just before it - is your dictionary a Swift `Dictionary`, or a Cocoa `NS{Mutable}Dictionary`?

Comment: Also, what happens if you make your object not a singleton? Maybe we can rule that out as part of the problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This looks to me like a concurrency issue. Swift dictionaries aren't thread safe, and using them from a singleton can lead to multiple reader/writer issues.

Edit: I am pretty sure this is the real answer, based on the given source/debugging dump. To correct what I wrote, specifically MUTABLE dictionaries and arrays (as well as NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray) aren't thread safe, and problems arise when using them within Singletons that are accessed from multiple threads, and that appears to be what the sample source code is doing, or enabling other parts of the code to do.

I don't have an Apple link discussing Swift collection class thread safety, but I"m pretty sure common knowledge. But the following tutorial on Grand Central Dispatch discusses the problem in depth and how to solve it using GCD.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1

Comment: Now that seems interesting. Could you detail a bit more your answer ? Why do you think that using them from a singleton can lead to multiple read/ write issues ? Where did you learn that Swift dictionaries are not thread safe, and do you think that NSDictionary are ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it's really related to Dictionaries, because I use Arrays in singletons a lot, and I never had such an issue ...

Comment: It seems `NSLock` (`lock` / `unlock`) solves the issues at least in my case. Is this OK solution to use `NSLock` in such a case?

Answer (score 2):

The error, and the line itself:

```
dictionary[index] = newValue!
```

makes me think the problem is `newValue` being `nil` - and the error is caused by the forced unwrapping.
I would suggest to set a breakpoint and check its value, or otherwise print it before adding to the dict.

Moreover, it wouldn't be a bad idea to protect that statement with an optional binding:

```
if let value = newValue {
    dictionary[index] = value
}
```

because if the value type is optional, it can be nil.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but it still crashes.
In fact, I had already checked that the newValue was not nil while debugging, but no, it has the following value :

Printing description of newValue:
(Double?) newValue = 1.2664

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

So in the end, I contacted Apple Technical Support.
They couldn't reproduce the issue.

I thought that maybe I don't need to save the currency rates, because during the quotes update, the function will check which currency rates it needs anyway, and repopulate the dictionary as needed.
So I deactivated the methods i created to save the CurrencyRateStore and to reload it again with NSKeyedUnarchiver.
Apparently, the crash is gone!

Comment: For other people seeing this: I fixed this problem by changing the name of the storage directory- suddenly the crash disappeared.